# Swift 3 Can't touch UIButton on the bottom of UIScroll

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a problem with Xcode 8 and Swift 3 UIButton inside UI ScrollView which the UIButton can't touch/tap. The structure of storyboard like this.

```
View
-Scroll View
--Content View
---Content Label (dynamic long content get from API)
---Agree Button
```

And this lines of codes for making scroll working with the dynamic label.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let maxLabelWidth: CGFloat = self.contentView.frame.size.width
    let neededSize = self.contentLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: maxLabelWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    self.contentView.frame.size.height = neededSize.height+self.agreeButton.frame.size.height+300
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.contentView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Everything is setup as default in the storyboard. Is there another configuration to solve this problem?

Comment: Show please full code of your setup

Answer (score 2):

It is highly likely that your UIButton is not within the bounds of its superview. That is usually the problem when I see this happen. Try setting the background color of the UIButton's superview to red or something and see if the button is within the red area.

Comment: You are right, Content View reaches the bottom of scroll view when I give it background. But, I don't understand why it's like that. I try to print to make sure Content View height same as Scroll View height and Label+button height, it is the same heights. What should I do to make Content view height updated?

Comment: Finally, I put this "self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true" after scrollView resize, the button works. But it makes over width to scrollview and it's content, even I added this line "contentViewWidthConstraints.constant = view.frame.width"